# How to print Package variable in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to print the package variable in the main package, how can I do that?

```
package temp;
$A = 10;
1;

package main;
$B = "A";
print $temp::$B;
1;
```

Comment: Consider declaring package variables with [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), and use [strict](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas. Do you want to print `$A` in the `temp` package from within the `main` package? That would be `print $temp::A, "\n"`?

Answer (score 1):

```perl
print $temp::A;
```

If you (horribly) want to use a "symbolic reference" as you appear to be doing,

```perl
my $var_name = "temp::A";
print do { no strict qw( refs ); $$var_name };
```